# Manually submitting coverage result to coveralls

Tags: bash, shell, docker

So i have a script `test.sh` which firsts build a test docker image then runs the docker image which in turn runs the test. I'ld like to manually add a command to send the coverage result to coveralls.io

Can anyone help with a clue to the right direction i'm heading?

Answer (score 2):

In general, manual submission to coveralls works as follows:

1. Add your repo in Coveralls, so that it's assigned a token.
2. Create a file `.coveralls.yml` which at minimum should contain this one line:

   ```
   repo_token: "coveralls-token-for-your-repo"
   ```
3. Run tests in a way that generates some file with coverage information.

   In Python, for example, you'd run `python3 -m coverage ...` and file `.coverage` will be created.
4. Submit to Coveralls, using a script that they provide.

   Again, taking Python for example, you'd do:

   ```
   $ pip3 install coveralls # a Python package for submitting to Coveralls
   $ coveralls # yes, just this
   ```

   The output might be:

   ```
   Submitting coverage to coveralls.io...
   Coverage submitted!
   Job #10.1
   https://coveralls.io/jobs/353453468453
   ```

   The `coveralls` command will look for `.coveralls.yml` file in the current directory, so be sure to put it there.

If you're not using Python, however, for steps 3. and 4. you'll need to read about generating and submitting coverage data for your language in [Coveralls docs](https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us). For selected languages the support is just as good as for Python, meaning that the commands might differ slightly, but it should still be a breeze.